# Prove that for any similar polygons the ratio of their areas is $a^2:b^2$

Tags: geometry

> Prove that for any similar polygons the ratio of their areas is
>   $a^2:b^2$ where $a:b$ is the ratio for the sides.

I'm looking for a rigorous proof of this intuitive theorem.  Can't seem to find one or construct one.  Also looking for proof of the same statement for the ratio of volumes.

Comment: Hint: what’s the formal definition of similarity when generalized to any shape in Euclidean space?

Comment: Firstly it's obvious by definition of the similarity. Also, you can make a triangulation of the first and the similar triangulation of the second.

Comment: Have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation